# -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "(null)" for ios 9 (swift)

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, parse-platform

I have seen many problems like my question.And i have  tried all solution .but i am getting this same problem.

**My Problem:**

when i click facebook login button ,its opening in safari and with in some seconds my page went off and return to facebook login button

**In both simulator and device i am getting this problem**

**My warning:**

```
 -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "(null)"
```

Here is my.plist :

[image]

How to fix this problem !

I also updated my plist with fbapi,fbauth string alone.But that time also not able to resolve my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it all about the `Facebook SDK`. I also face this problem .So my suggestion is to use the `latest Facebook SDK`.If you are using only for login means - you can add `coreKit`,`LoginKit` and use `fbauth2` alone for your problem.No need to add others items.Latest [Facebook SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios). Or try to use the V4.6.0 SDK.Here is the link [Older SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/downloads)

Hope this help